# Insert average value using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to calculate average value of column=ServiceQuality from table=iis1, while updating the value into table=adminsum, column=avevalue WHERE the aname='SERVICEQUALITY'.

The table in phpmyadmin looks like this:

```
dbname=iis ; table name=adminsum;

UserID          aname              avevalue
  1        SERVICEQUALITY   (insert average value here) 
  2              USE        (insert average value here)
```

I want the average value in adminsum kept up to date whenever the average value from table=iis1, column=ServiceQuality changes.

Here is my coding but it seems I missed up something and didn't work.
It is just inserting 0 value but not the exact average value.

Can anyone help me on this?

```
<?php

 require_once('Connections/localhost.php');
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("iis");

// Make a MySQL Connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

$query = "SELECT AVG (ServiceQuality) AS average from iis1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$query1 = "UPDATE adminsum SET avevalue='average' WHERE aname='SERVICEQUALITY'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (!mysql_query($query,$conn))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_close($conn)
?>
```

Comment: (a) That is going to be costly to do; (b) it should be done by a triggered action in the DBMS, not by PHP-level code; (c) you should be writing something like `UPDATE adminsum SET avevalue = (SELECT AVG(ServiceQuality) FROM iis1) WHERE aname = 'SERVICEQUALITY'`, but it will be embedded in a CREATE TRIGGER statement, or in a procedure called from a CREATE TRIGGER statement.

Comment: Please guide me @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I outlined how to do it.  You can read the manual ([CREATE TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html), [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)) just as well as I can.

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate that

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in a single step using a subquery.

Change your query to be:

```
update adminsum
set avevalue = ( select avg(ServiceQuality) from iis1 )
where aname = 'SERVICEQUALITY'
```